# Vertical alignment using just 2 divs

Tags: css

I have a container div and a content div. 
markup:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
   <pre>
      some <br/>
      content <br/> of variable height.
   </pre>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {display:table; border:solid red 2px; width:400px; height:500px; background-color:#aaa;}

#content {display:table-cell; height:200px; width:200px; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#444}
```

I want to vertically align the content div, but not have it take the complete height of the container div.
Now I see other solutions for this, the ones that use 3 div's - outer, middle, inner- I don't want to do that- just 2 divs. 
While the above thing works- the height of the content div is ignored- possibly because of the table-cell display value, and it fills the entire container div. How to rectify this??

Comment: what is you question?

Comment: Your markup is not valid, there is no closing tag for the first div. And what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: there, it's valid now

Comment: What are you wanting to vertically align? The Text? The Div? In your example you don't have anything to vertically align things to.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the display:table-cell css from your #content id css selector, then the 200 height is respected. And you have a typo in your height: 200px width:200px there is no semi-colon separating the two values, so the width is not getting applied.

```css
#container {
    display:table;
    border:solid red 2px;
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#aaa;
}
#content {
    /*display:table-cell;*/
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#444
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"> <pre>
      some <br/>
      content <br/> of variable height.
   </pre>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: corrected the typo in css. If i remove display:table-cell- the content div will not vertically align itself with respect to the container div.

Comment: This example uses 3 divs- http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: and i want to use just 2 divs for this